# jQuery - take classes from 1 element and add to another

Tags: html, jquery

I have the following:

```html
<div id="main" class="col-lg-7 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-md-push-3 col-lg-push-3">
  <div id="inner">
  </div>
</div>
```

How would I take the classes from `#main` and add them to `#inner`. These classes change from page to page but they need to match. So I guess I will need `addClass` to be a variable?

The reason I am trying to achieve this is `#inner` becomes fixed and therefore looses the inheritance.

Comment: _"...but need to match"_ - Why do they also have to be at `#inner`?

Comment: Assuming there's no classes set on `#inner`, just use `$('#inner').prop('class', $('#main').prop('class'))` ***however*** this is a very odd requirement as you could simply use CSS rules on `#inner` based on the classes on the parent, eg. `.one #inner`

Comment: The example is a bit loose but its a layout thing. Basically #inner becomes fixed and therefore needs to have those classes applied.

Comment: 'Basically #inner becomes fixed and therefore needs to have those classes applied' Fixed positioning makes no difference to styling inherited from parent elements, nor class rules based on them: https://jsfiddle.net/48mLvkqu/

Comment: OK a bit more context. Say these classes are controlling classes. Like col-md-8 etc. Let me change the example

Comment: What have you tried?  Please add the code you have tried here and we can help you fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to get those classes on the load of the page. So, you have to add such script,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var mainClasses = $("#main").attr("class");
  $("#inner").addClass(mainClasses);
});
```

If you need to remove the classes from **#main** and add it to **#inner**, just add the line below .addClass();

```
$("#main").removeClass(mainClasses);
```

Comment: Note that using `attr` will only get the classes that were present in the HTML that came from the server. If any script has made modifications to the class list, use `prop`.

Comment: @HereticMonkey not exactly. You can try it with script-based classes too.

Answer (score 0):

firstly you have to get the element by Id and store it in any variable.

```js
var li = document.getElementById('main');
```

then add that variable classes into another div id:

```js
$('#inner').addClass(li.className);
```